# Задание нецелочисленных свойств в css

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, width

Как задать `aside{float:right;width:33%-143.156px}` ?

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду? Задать можно через точку, например: width: 15.1% Вычислить можно с помощью функции calc()

Answer (score 1):

Для подобных вычислений в CSS существует функция **[calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/calc())** :

```css
aside {
  float: right;
  width: calc(33% - 143.156px);
}
```